# Log4jConfigListener cannot be found -- context fails to start

Tags: java, spring, jsp, web-applications, tomcat6

I am trying to set up a web application on Eclipse. I am using Tomcat 6.0 and jdk 1.6.0_23.
For some reason I am getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4078)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Jan 24, 2011 11:44:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4078)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I checked if all libraries have been added to the build path and everything seems correct. log4j-1.2.15.jar is included and all the necessary spring libraries.

I am very confused as to what the problem especially because the project was working fine in another computer. Any help with this problem will be highly appreciated.

Naftal

Comment: can you list out libraries you have included

Comment: I am using Hibernate so I have hibernate libraries such as hibernate-annotations.jar, hibernate3.jar etc. But according to the stacktrace, it seems I am missing one of the springframework librabries. I have these spring libraries:- spring.jar, spring-aop.jar, spring-aspects.jar, spring-beans.jar, spring-context.jar, spring-context-support.jar, spring-core.jar, spring-jdbc.jar, spring-test.jar, spring-web.jar, spring-webmvc.jar

Comment: ok then there is no spring jar ,is it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener class is definitely not in your classpath.

The first thing I would suggest is that you turn up the logging level in Tomcat -- in the conf folder -- to "ALL" or "DEBUG" so that you can see exactly what is going on in the container that is preventing this class from being found.

Second, I'd recommend you check your JAR files for the missing class file by running grep, if on linux/mac:

```
  # run at the root of your lib folders:
  grep -ri "org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener" *
```

The above command will return all JAR files that contain that package.  Once the JAR file is isolated, then you can further troubleshoot.

Third, make sure you don't have any conflicts.  Multiple versions of Log4j being in your classpath will wreak havoc.  How is the system supposed to know **which** org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener package to load if there are 2 of them?  Tomcat has 3 different classpath folders:

```
 shared/lib
 lib
 webapps/yourapp/WEB-INF/lib
```

Make sure you have only one log4j JAR file in only one of these folders.

Comment: I will just remove all the libraries and start from scratch. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 42):

Reticulogic's second suggestion is correct.  However, in Eclipse Helios, the "Java EE Module Dependencies" option has been removed.  The fix for Helios is as follows:

1. Right click on your project in Eclipse and go to Properties-->Deployment Assembly
2. Click "Add..."
3. Select "Java Build Path Entries" and click "Next"
4. select "Maven Dependencies" and click "Finish"

Comment: Thanks so much! Been stuck on this for ages - Bounty coming your way.

Comment: Also check that "Enable dependency management" under Properties --> Maven is selected..

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to clean the Tomcat directory in Eclipse. It worked for me.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: In Eclipse Mars, in the servers view pane, right click on the server instance, then pick either "Clean..." or "Clean Tomcat Work Directory..."

Answer (score 3):

If you are using maven and eclipse

1) Look in your web project .classpath file.  If you have a classpath entry "org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER", then make sure the attribute is there as well.

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

2)  If that does not work, then right click on your web project in eclipse and go to Properties-->JavaEE Module dependencies.  Make sure the Maven Dependencies box is checked.

Then save, build deploy yada yada

Answer (score 2):

> Migrating to log4j2?

Don't forget to check your webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml (Web Application Deployment Descriptor) for extraneous Event Listener definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use, log4j2, you can find these classes in

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.web.*
```

package.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the class name `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener` is part of spring framework.
And it was depricated since spring 4.2.1 . So check your spring version.

Comment: Spring 4.0 was not even released back then......

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to proof that Log4JConfigListener was deprecated after Spring 4.2.1?

Comment: Sure. [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.2.5.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html)